# All products except ones of a category

Tags: magento-1.8

I want to get a list of all products which are not in a specific category.

Answer (score 2):

You can get first the list of products in that category then exclude the ids.
Not sure this is the best way to do it but it works.

```
$productsIdsInCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->getAllIds();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin'=>$productsIdsInCategory));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$categoryIds = array(2,4);//category id

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                             ->getCollection()
                             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('nin' => $categoryIds))
                             ->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503534/display-magento-products-by-category-id

Comment: Thanks, but i get an error "Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "744" already exist". I have to say that i use flat tables. Maybe that's the problem? Here's the complete code: 

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->setStoreId($storeId)
->addStoreFilter($storeId)
->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('type_id', array('like' => 'simple'))
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('nin' => array(168)));

Comment: Try adding `->groupByAttribute('entity_id');`

Comment: Did adding ->groupByAttribute this work?